# Specify encoding in manifest file

Tags: java, utf-8, jar, manifest, manifest.mf

I created a jar using the Export functionality in Eclipse and when I try to execute it in the following way it fails

```
java -jar Code.jar
```

However it works correctly for

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar Code.jar
```

Current manifest file

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: test.Reader
Class-Path: .
```

How can I mention the encoding inside the manifest file? So that I dont have to mention it explicitly while running the jar file?

Comment: MANIFEST.MF is always UTF8 (https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/specs/jar/jar.html#name-value-pairs-and-sections)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This indicates a problem with your code.  Your code is currently depending on the default platform encoding, and doesn't work if that encoding is not "UTF-8".  therefore, you should change the places in your code which depend on the default platform encoding to use the "UTF-8" encoding explicitly.

and, no, you can't specify that in the manifest.

Comment: you are right, i had not mentioned the default charset while creating my output streams and now it is working, thanks!